# How to send dynamic html content in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, html-email

I have an ASP.Net MVC application. I need to send html content from HTML-Editor. but I have problem with it.

This is my Html-Editor:

[image]

This is my code:

```
public void MailMessageHtml(string body, string subject, string from, IEnumerable<string> to)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail@example.com"));
        message.From = new MailAddress(_Settings.MailServer.UserName);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        var htmlBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

        message.AlternateViews.Add(
            AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(string.Empty, new ContentType("text/plain")));

        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlBody);

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = _Settings.MailServer.UserName,
                Password = _Settings.MailServer.Password
            };
            smtp.Credentials = credential;
            smtp.Host = _Settings.MailServer.IPAddress;
            smtp.Port = _Settings.MailServer.Port;
            smtp.EnableSsl = _Settings.MailServer.EnableSSL;
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

but the html content in Email's body has shown like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: So many details, yet no explanation of what your 'problem' is...

Comment: can you please show whole function? And the call part please.

Comment: Is that plain text? If you specify plain text in body then that should be used for clients that do not render html.

Comment: I have edited the question for some clarification.

Comment: Your HTML is probably being encoded so you are sending HTML but the brackets are being encoded to &lt; and &gt;...

Comment: I know it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Decode the content before passing the content to the body.

```
body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
```

Just this.